# View image in a seperate View Controller from UICollectionView Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview

So I am creating a UiCollectionView. You can scroll through an array of images in the collection view, and whenever you tap on one of the images, it will take you into a separate view controller and display the image that you tapped on from the UICollectionView. I have watched tutorials and followed step by step but I don’t know what I am doing wrong. I can view the collection view and scroll though it but as soon as I tap on one of the images it doesn’t go to the separate view controller. I have checked my classes and identifiers. I have them all correct.

The `collectionView` is an outlet called `collectionView`

The `UIimage` in the `collectionViewCell` is an outlet called

The `collectionViewCell` identifier is `“Cell”`

The `collectionViewCell` class is `OurCell`

The `viewController` that will hold the image is called the `secondViewController`

Here is the code for the `ViewController` class file:

```
@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

let imageArray = [UIImage(named: "EliHouse1" ), UIImage(named: "EliHouse2"), UIImage(named: "EliHouse3" ), UIImage(named: "iPod" )]

func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {

    return 1

}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {



    return self.imageArray.count


}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! OurCell


    cell.ourImage?.image = self.imageArray[indexPath.row]



    return cell

}




func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)
{
    if segue.identifier == "showImage"
    {
        let indexPaths = self.collectionView!.indexPathsForSelectedItems!
        let indexPath = indexPaths[0] as NSIndexPath
        let vc = segue.destination as! SecondViewController
        vc.image = self.imageArray[indexPath.row]!

    }
}
```

Here is the code for the `OurCell` class file

```
@IBOutlet weak var ourImage: UIImageView!
```

Here is the code for the `SecondViewController` class file

```
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
var image = UIImage()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    self.imageView.image = self.image

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

I run it in the code and I can view and scroll through the cells, but whenever I tap an image it does not take me to the `SecondViewController` and nothing happens. Does anybody have any ideas? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where do you define the `showImage` segue identifier? Can you show us your storyboard as well?

Comment: First of all there is no need to type convert `IndexPath` instance to `NSIndexPath` you can directly use `IndexPath`, Also in `storyboard` have you created segue from `UICollectionViewCell` to `SecondViewController`?

Answer (score 0):

In your collectionView class, you should add something like this:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let identifier = "showImage"
    if segue.identifier == identifier {
        let indexPath = collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems
        if let indexPath = indexPath?.first,
            let cell = collectionView(rssCollectionView, cellForItemAt: indexPath) as? OurCell,
            let image = cell.ourImage (or something like this to retrieve the picture) {
            let showImage = segue.destination as? SecondViewController
            showImage?.image = image
        }
    }
```

Also, in the storyboard you need to command+drag form the collectionView cell to another your secondViewController and select segue with the desired kind and then select the line for segue and add "showImage" in the identifier text field.